# SharePoint App: Deploy custom action to entire site collection

Tags: sharepoint, custom-action, sharepoint-online

I am developing an app that extends document libraries with a set of file management features (such like copy/move, zip etc) triggered by a series of custom actions. The app works fine, but I am having issues getting it deployed to the entire site collection. The objective is to have the custom action on all document libraries in the site collection and of course newly created webs.

How do I achieve this? I have tried app stapling and the app shows up fine on all webs but the custom actions are not deployed to the document libraries in the webs.

Any idea how to get it to work.

Thanks, Xavier

Answer (score 2):

The custom action is defined in an "app" not a "solution" so using Scope ="site" in the feature definition is not supported and thus the app is nor validated nor deployed.

Driving me nuts .... I just want to have a custom action deployed to the entire site collection and newly created webs, wrapped in an app with an Azure hosted AppWeb...

Surely I am not the first...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this blog post will help: http://blog.mastykarz.nl/deploying-custom-actions-app-model/

Basically he uses client side code to upload the custom actions resources to the host site collection and finally registers the custom action code there as well.

Answer (score -2):

when you create a custom action you can use the below 2 lines to make sure that it will be applied to all document libraries along with the new one.
your code inside CustomAction.xml file should contains the 2 lines below.

```
RegistrationType="List"
RegistrationId="101"
```

for more about registration id, please see the link below.
http://techtrainingnotes.blogspot.de/2008/01/sharepoint-registrationid-list-template.html

later when you will create the feature to deploy this custom action, you can set the scope as site collection.

```
<Feature  Id="GUID"
      Title="Title of your feature"
      Description="Description here"
      Version="12.0.0.0"
      Hidden="FALSE"
      Scope="Site" -- this is for site collection
      DefaultResourceFile="core"
      xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
    <ElementManifests>
        <ElementManifest Location="elements.xml"/>
        <ElementManifest Location="CustomAction.xml"/>
    </ElementManifests>
 </Feature>
```

Hope this helps you !!

Comment: This is not supported for Add-Ins. The OP has explicitly asked for Add.In (formerly known as Apps).